# Need to convert Sybase query to SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, sybase

```
SELECT     
         gasqlty_cylinder.qualification_date,   
         gas_qlty_cylinder.location_id,   
         gas_qlty_lab.lab_desc,   
         gas_qlty_cylinder.start_date,   
         gas_qlty_cylinder.end_date,   
         analysis_data.date_set,   
         analysis_data.date_removed,   
         analysis_data.btu,   
         analysis_data.spec_gvty,   
         gas_qlty_cylinder.remarks,   
         gas_qlty_cylinder.mcsusr_id,   
         gas_qlty_cylinder.trans_timestamp  
FROM     gasqltycylinder,   
         analysisdata ,  
         gasqltylocation,   
         gasqltylab  
WHERE    ( gas_qlty_cylinder.cylinder_id *= analysis_data.`cylinder_id` ) and  
         ( gas_qlty_location.location_id = gas_qlty_cylinder.location_id ) and
         ( gas_qlty_location.lab_id = gas_qlty_lab.lab_id ) and  
         ( analysis_data.analyzed_time =* ( select max(analyzed_time) from analysis_data 
    where gas_qlty_cylinder.cylinder_id = analysis_data.cylinder_id and
    ))   
Order by cylinder_id
```

Comment: You could run this by setting the database compatibility level to 80.

=* are basically outer joins, that are using a very - very - very old syntax. This is just an FYI - you really should rewrite this, where you see =* use LEFT OUTER join.

Comment: yes . after rewritting my query .. I need exact query in sql server.

Comment: This is one of those "here is my script, fix it" questions. Ask a specific question and give it a try yourself. Converting it is not that hard.

Comment: @Alex: Just for the record: SQL Server 2012 doesn't support the compatibility level of 80.

Answer (score 0):

*= and =* style joins have been [deprecated since SQL Server 2008](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143729%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) and [discontinued in SQL Server 2012](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144262%28sql.110%29.aspx).

Rewrite your query, *= being LEFT OUTER JOIN and =* RIGHT OUTER JOIN. Some quick guideline with examples from MS: [link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187518%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

Also, remove the ` symbols from the query.